# I want to stop submitting the whole page and submit only my form using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, flask

I have added the JS and HTML code. It will submit the whole page but I do not want that. I want to only submit my form.

```js
function submit_by_id()
  {
   var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
   var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
   if (!validation()) // Calling validation function
   {
    return false;
   }
   else
   {
    alert("working fine");
    return true;
   }
  }
  

  
form validation function currently for email and pwd

  function validation()
  {
   var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
   var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
   if (name === '' || email === '')
   {
    alert("Please fill all fields...!!!!!!");
    return false;
   }
   else
   {
   return true;
   }
  }

this is html code
```

```html
<form name ="myform" id="myform"  onsubmit=" return submit_by_id()" action="#">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email address:</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">name:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
      </div>
      <button type="Submit"   class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
     </form>
```

Comment: `submit_by_id()` your function gets an event object, you should call event.preventDefault in your function

Comment: You don't need to put return before submit_by_id() in the onsubmit event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for technique where page not get submitted,

read through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX

an easy library would be https://github.com/axios/axios

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use a function for validation, just use "required"

`<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required>`

to stop the page from reloading on submit use `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: specifically, Where should  i user this event.preventDefault()

Answer (score 0):

```js
   

function submit_by_id()
  {
   var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
   var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
   alert("working fine");
  }
```

```html
<form name ="myform" id="myform" action="#" onsubmit=" return submit_by_id()" required>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="email">Email address:</label>
   <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="name">name:</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required> 
  </div>
  <button   class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
 </form>
```